# SSH doesnt restart on reboot after upgrade to Ubuntu Vivid Vervet 15.04

Tags: boot, 15.04, sshd

I recently upgraded my server to Ubuntu Vivid Vervet 15.04 from 14.04.2 LTS

The upgrade went fine, and I could SSH into the server no problem. It was only when I restarted the server (using restart -r now) a few weeks later I discovered that the SSH daemon no longer starts up automatically when the server is rebooted.

This means I can't SSH into my server. I get the following error message

ssh: connect to host [host name not included here] port 22: Connection refused

I can access the server through a rescue-mode at OVH but does anyone know what I have to do to get the server to start SSH automatically on reboot in 15.04? Vivid vervet now uses *systemd* as default instead of UpStart so things are very different in terms of start-up scripts, which is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu 15.04. We have a systemd however upstart scripts should work as well. If you have upgraded and the SSH daemon is not starting automatically. Please do the below via a Terminal.

## sudo systemctl enable sshd

After this the System will start ssh daemon (sshd) automatically at boot.

Comment: Yes it does , After telling systemd to add sshd to start at boot ,it will start automatically. I am telling from experience and not just speculating